# Login with Email/GMail in ios

Tags: ios

I want to add "Login with Email" functionality in ios app.

I searched about this, but i found that we can not get default email account of iPhone.

Can anybody suggest me how should i proceed for this issue. Thanx in advance.

Comment: can u ask the question in clearly plz

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I want to implement "Login With Email" functionality in my iOS app. I want to identify the user based on his Email ID.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, In my application I have comments section, where user can post comment. Now, I want to identify the user who has posted comment. I provided three functionalities, "Login with Facebook", "Login with Twitter" and "Login with Email". Can you tell em how to implement "Login with Email" in ios app.

Comment: see first understand the concept, Login with Facebook means via Facebook through k , Login with Twitter - via twitter and finally Login with Email means -- via in manual login (use your backend server)or with gmail

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Can you tell me how to implement this without backend server?.

Comment: in w/o server u need to use in the local DB, actually I m not get in your point, if u ask correct ? , i surely hope with u

Comment: I want to this with gmail or any mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link for your login with gmail http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/

will u need just like this , here i used

1. Login with FB
2. Login with Twitter
3. Login with manually
         -- here i used server and Sqlite for save the user information

   ```
               -- email, name, p/wd, phone number, etc. 


      -- this login accessing with our own db or server
   ```

Comment: here which type of the answer do u need

Comment: I don't have backend DB and server also. I want to verify user credentials from gmail or yahoo like I did with Facebook and Twitter. Is there any library or framework using which i can validate user?.

Comment: thank you very much.. You helped me.. Can you tell me if I want to use any email account?. What should I do in that case?. User may not have gmail account, then how to identify that user?.

Comment: ya ur ? is nice, and u r get in the single string , u can't validate to the multiple , here u need to implement the core data or sqlite for saving and validate function

Comment: if u need any assistance call in my mail id

Answer (score 0):

Of all the apps that ask for email and password, none get it directly from the iPhone settings, which makes me believe that there must be some sort of restriction for gathering that information.

So, then the procedure is  ask for email and password from the user directly, fire a url to validate and check for the user with those credentials and either login or ask him/her to sign up